# Is it possible a Golang package in subdir not included by default?

Tags: go

I am using a golang package, say name `pkgfoo`; and the author explicitly said if we want to use a package `subpkg` under `pkgfoo`, I need to explicitly import subpkg. I don't understand the reason behind it. Isn't the subpkg automatically imported if I import the top pkg in Golang?

```
package main

import (
    "myownpackage"

    "github.com/usera/pkgfoo"
    "github.com/usera/pkgfoo/subpkg"
)

func main() {
    // Use functions in pkgfoo, and use functions in pkgfoo/subpkg
    // ......
    http.HandleFunc("/login", login)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil) // setting listening port
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

My question is whether I really need `import "github.com/usera/pkgfoo/subpkg"` statement.

Comment: YOu only need to import a package if you want to use it. If you do not want to use it (either directly or through its init side effects): Don't import it. There are no "subpackages" in Go.

Comment: The easiest way to test your question would be to remove the import and see if the program compiles. If not you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go packages are constructed from one or more source files, which are organized into folders in the file system. Source files of the same package must be in the same folder.

But in Go there is no "package hierarchy", the "subpackage" term simply refers to the folder of a package being a *subfolder* of another. We often organize packages to be in folders being subfolders of others because there is some connection between those packages (e.g. a package is used only by another being in the parent folder; or a package in a subfolder is a specific or more special implementation of the package in the parent folder; or simply just a logical grouping - see the end of the answer).

So whenever you do

```
import "github.com/usera/pkgfoo"
```

It only imports `pkgfoo` and no other packages sharing the same path as prefix. If you need `github.com/usera/pkgfoo/subpkg` too, you also need to explicitly import it:

```
import (
    "github.com/usera/pkgfoo"
    "github.com/usera/pkgfoo/subpkg"
}
```

---

[The Go Blog: Package names](https://blog.golang.org/package-names) on directories used in the standard library:

> **Directories.** The standard library uses like directories `crypto`, `container`, `encoding`, and `image` to group packages for related protocols and algorithms. There is no actual relationship among the packages in one of these directories; a directory just provides a way to arrange the files. Any package can import any other package provided the import does not create a cycle.